# Destroy transit js on object

Tags: jquery, transition

I've recently been trying out [Transit JS](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for some animation on thumbnails. It's not essential i use transit js, which could be a good thing as i can't find a way to destroy the animation call on my div if i need to.

Basically i am looking to try and disable the animations for mobile, as there is no hover on mobile, it's pointless leaving this in there. But going through the documentation, i can't seem to find a way to stop the process.

My code looks like this:

```
  $(".spark_burst").css({ scale: 0 });

  $("a.trigger").bind('mouseenter play', function() {
    $(this).find(".spark_burst").transition({
        opacity: 0.7, scale: 2,
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'in',
        queue:false,
        complete: function() {  }
      });
    $(this).find(".targeting").transition({
      y: 0,
      x: 235,
      easing: 'in',
      queue:false,
      duration: 200 
    });
  }).bind('mouseleave reset', function() {
            console.log("hover out");
      $(this).find(".spark_burst").transition({
        opacity: 0, scale: 0,
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'out',
        queue:false,
        complete: function() {  }
      });
      $(this).find(".targeting").transition({
        y: 0,
        x: 0,
        easing: 'snap',
        queue:false,
        duration: 200 
      });
  });
```

I've tried to unbind the event like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){  
  if ($("#all_spark").css("marginRight") == "0px" ){

    console.log("0 pixels");
    $("a.trigger").unbind( "mouseover mouseout play reset" );

  }
});
```

My thought process here was set a resize function to watch for when a mobile style is trigger on the parent, then unbind the `mouseover` and `mouseout` triggers. But this was a shot in the dark and doesn't work so i am guessing this is pure rubbish on my part.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to the trigger,

and unbind `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, but it does not work.....

....

**BUT WAIT !!! THEY ARE TOTALLY DIFFERENT EVENTS!**

**[mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)** is not the same as **[mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)**,

and

**[mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)** is not the same as **[mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)**,

to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) a event, you need use the same event name :)

Tested with this transit JS in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JuKqK/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, i overlooked the fact i was referencing different events, that would do the trick.